# Which statistical hypothesis test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Or: Should such a test be applied here at all?

I am investigating whether archaeological sites (type_1, see example data) are located in certain natural areas (e.g. altitude, elev_class). Here is an example data set:

| elev_class | percentage | type_1 | type_1_expected_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 505-569 | 5.25 | 1 | 2 |
| 569-632 | 14.4 | 2 | 6 |
| 632-695 | 24.1 | 7 | 10 |
| 695-759 | 38.1 | 22 | 15 |
| 759-822 | 18.2 | 8 | 7 |

As R data.frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(elev_class = c("505-569", "569-632", "632-695", 
    "695-759", "759-822"),elev_percentage = c("5.25", "14.4", 
    "24.1", "38.1", "18.2"), type_1 = c("1", "2", "7", "22", 
    "8"), type_1_expected_value = c("2","6","10","15","7")
                 )
```

For a graphical representation I create density plots for the height, the sites and a random distribution. This already gives a good overview of whether the sites are randomly distributed or not. However, I would like to test this statistically.
I have first classified the heights and calculated the total proportion of the class in the landscape (percentage column). Then I assign the sites to the respective classes. From the percentage of the classes, I can then create a probability vector and test it, for example, with the chi-square test:
(in R):

```r
chisq.test(df$type1, p=df$percentage/100)
```

Now the question:
Does this make sense with such a small database? Is my procedure correct? Is it advisable to use a different test procedure?

It would also be nice to be able to make a statistical statement for each row. For example, type 1 is statistically significantly associated with elev_class 695-759. Which procedure would be preferable here?

Comment: Do you have actual counts?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The column type_1 contains the actually counted observations. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chi squared distribution of the test statistic is an approximation for large samples, often recommended only if the expected count in every cell is larger than 5, which is not the case here. You could run the test with `simulate.p.value=TRUE`, which also works for smaller samples.

The bigger problem is whether testing this null hypothesis makes sense at all. A major assumption of the null model is that the counted events are all independent. Arguably archaeological sites are not, as people communicate with each other, there are connections etc. (although to some extent it depends on your collection of sites how important such dependence may be). So rejecting the null hypothesis would basically tell you something that you could know already without even looking at the data. The idea that sites could occur properly randomly is pretty silly if you think about it.

As far as I see it, only non-rejection would tell you something here, namely that surely from the data one can *not* take evidence that there is an association between type 1 and any of the classes. A rejection can have all kinds of explanations apart from having a preference for certain areas.

Comment: Thank you very much for your opinion. I completely agree with you that a random distribution of archaeological sites is very unlikely. 
Probably, natural factors (e.g. altitude, soil types) play a role in the selection of the settlement area (among other factors). However, I don't necessarily know in advance which factors these are. In this respect, the information as to whether type_1 is associated with a variable or a single class is interesting. Of course, the information is also important if there is no connection. But perhaps I have misunderstood you? (statistics is new territory for me)

Comment: The problem may be that a statistical test can do less than you hope (there's a big controversy going on about statistical tests and their misuse). A test assesses whether data are realistic assuming a certain model (the null hypothesis). If the null hypothesis is rejected, any feature of the model might be responsible for this (such as lack of independence, which apparently isn't your primary interest). If the null hypothesis is not rejected, this doesn't mean it is true. It only means that the data cannot be used to argue against it.

Comment: In your place I'd probably run the test, however don't over-interpret it. If it is not significant, it is correct to say that the data hold no evidence that a certain class is favoured by type_1, but of course the data set is small, it could be that with more data something can be found (with a small data set there are obviously limits to how much can be found out.). If there is significance, there are several different possible explanations for it, not just your primary topic of interest.

Comment: Thank you very much again for your explanations. It helped me a lot! If it's not too much trouble, do you have any literature references on the controversy you mentioned?

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10654-016-0149-3 https://errorstatistics.com/2021/06/20/at-long-last-the-asa-presidents-task-force-statement-on-statistical-significance-and-replicability/ https://errorstatistics.com/2019/11/14/the-asas-p-value-project-why-its-doing-more-harm-than-good-cont-from-11-4-19/ https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2021/07/12/thoughts-on-the-american-statistical-association-presidents-task-force-statement-on-statistical-significance-and-replicability/